# getElementById from select box to text field

Tags: database, getelementbyid, drop-down-menu

Im making a selectbox with the values from my DB, and I want to write the ID of the selected item to a textbox.

How can it be done? I have this code..

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="submitKon">
    <fieldset>
    <table class="opretTable" border="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="180" height="30"><label for="valgtkon" class="labelLeft">Vælg konkurrencetype</label></td> 
    <td><select id="valgtTitel" name="valgtTitel" onchange="run()">                  
    <?php
    $virksomhedsID = $_SESSION['virkID'];
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM konkurrenceType ORDER BY konkurrenceType.kontypeID";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());                  

    echo '<option value="Vælg type">Vælg type</option>';

    while($rowSelect = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    { 

        echo '<option value="' . $rowSelect['kontypeID'] . '">' . $rowSelect['kontypeTitel'] . '</option>';
    }?>                    
    </select>
```

and..

```
<script>
function run() {
    document.getElementById("valgtID").value = document.getElementById("valgtTitel").value;
}
</script>
```

I get this

```
INSERT INTO `mah1233411190550`.`konkurrence` ( `konID` , `virkID` , `konTitel` , `konBeskriv` , `konMaal` , `konMaaltype` , `konStart` , `konSlut`, `kontypeID`, `holdID` ) VALUES (NULL , '1', '1', 'cykle', '500', 'km', '2013-01-01', '2018-05-03', '1', '' );
```

So konTitel is the same as kontypeID, why is that?

Comment: @X.Jacobs what did you edit?

Comment: [click here](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13942992/revisions)

Comment: ah!
Do you know whats wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
var valgtTitel = document.getElementById("valgtTitel");
document.getElementById("valgtID").value = valgtTitel.options[valgtTitel.selectedIndex].value;
```

Here's fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/viralpatel/JYHLM/

**Edit:**
Perhaps you might want to save the title (apart from ID) in some other textbox and retrieve it from request:

```
var valgtTitel = document.getElementById("valgtTitel");
document.getElementById("valgtTitle").value = valgtTitel.options[valgtTitel.selectedIndex].innerHTML;
```

Note how we used `innerHTML` instead of `value` to get the title.

Comment: Hi thank you for answering.
Its the same, konTitel is the same as kontypeID, why is that?

Comment: INSERT INTO `mah1233411190550`.`konkurrence` ( `konID` , `virkID` , `konTitel` , `konBeskriv` , `konMaal` , `konMaaltype` , `konStart` , `konSlut`, `kontypeID`, `holdID` ) VALUES (NULL , '1', '3', 'løfte', '200', 'kg', '2013-01-01', '2018-05-03', '3', '' );

Comment: You question says you want to update textbox value with selected item. Is that what you looking for? Seems you are saving the values later and getting some differences there.

Comment: Yes you're right. It does in fact write the id, so i guess the question is solved. What I'm trying to do is get the ID and the Title from the selectbox and textfield and insert it again with
$kontypeID = $_POST['valgtID']; $konTitel = $_POST['valgtTitel']; But my sql writes either valgtID twice or valgtTitel twice, doy you know why that is?

Comment: You'l get value of selectbox once it got submitted. As in your case values of both selectbox & textbox is ID, you get ID. You should save the value somewhere on page as you loose it as soon as page renders.

Comment: and can you tell me how to change the values of the textbox to Title instead?

Comment: Just updated the ans. You need to assign `innerHTML` instead of `value` to that textbox. So you'll get both ID and value once you submit the form.

Comment: can you please tell me the difference between value and innerhtml?
Is it that value gets lost and innerhtml stays?

Answer (score 0):

So something like this??

```
                <tr>
                <td width="180" height="30"><label for="valgtkon" class="labelLeft">Vælg konkurrencetype</label></td> 
                <td><select id="select" name="select" onchange="run()">                  
                <?php
                $virksomhedsID = $_SESSION['virkID'];
                $sql = "SELECT * FROM konkurrenceType ORDER BY konkurrenceType.kontypeID";
                $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());                  

                echo '<option value="Vælg type">Vælg type</option>';

                while($rowSelect = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                { 
                    $kontypeID = $rowSelect['kontypeID'];
                    $kontypeTitel = $rowSelect['kontypeTitel'];             
                    echo '<option value="' . $kontypeID . '">' . $kontypeTitel . '</option>';
                }?>                    
                </select></td>
                <script>
                function run() {
                    var select = document.getElementById("select");
                    document.getElementById("valgtID").value = valgtTitel.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML; //how to make this right?
                    document.getElementById("valgtTitel").value = valgtTitel.options[select.selectedIndex].innerHTML; //how to make this right?
                }
                </script>


                <td><input type="text" name="valgtID" id="valgtID"/><input type="text" name="valgtTitel" id="valgtTitel"/></td>
                </tr>
```

Comment: @ViralPatel what do you think?